# How to remove string/character, if its surrounded by the space, see below for details

Tags: php

I am trying to use the function `str_replace()` to replace everything when a space appears.

For example lets say i have the string 'OFFERS + PROMOTIONS' - I want the function to delete everything when a empty space appears.

So the function should output OFFERSPROMOTIONS.

The code which I was playing with is below.

```
<?php

$title = get_the_title();

$titlereplace = str_replace(' ', '', $title);

$lowercase = strtolower($titlereplace);

?>
```

Comment: You want to remove only spaces or delete all the string when there are spaces?

Comment: Not understanding what you want to delete? please explain.

Comment: I want to remove everything between spaces - so lets say test + test is a string the output should be testtest.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. It will erase everything between two spaces along with them.

```
$string = preg_replace('~ [^ ]* ~U', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Or just for spaces, try :

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```